# Add explanatory link to "not constructive" to closed questions footer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, not-constructive

Since we've [changed the "subjective and argumentative" close reason to "not constructive"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89417/make-not-constructive-a-close-reason-across-the-stack-exchange-network), can we add the very useful link that is present in the close-vote dialog to the actual footer of closed questions as well?  As is, the close reason presented to the voter and the rationale presented to those seeing the close notice don't sync up and it clouds the issue.

Something like:

> ### closed as [not constructive](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) by <closer_list> <time_since_close>
>
> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

or if you'd rather not have a link in the close reason like that, just add it onto the end of the explanation:

> ### closed as not constructive by <closer_list> <time_since_close>
>
> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.  It does not meet enough of our [six guidelines for constructive subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Whenever people link to that blog post I feel I have to highlight the bit near the end that states `You can expect to see these guidelines enforced ... wherever subjectivity is part of the site topic itself.`. I know these guidelines can be useful in general, but pointing people to these guidelines from sites which *don't* have a subjective focus within their scope is possibly asking for trouble...

Comment: I would have appreciated the additional link to the topic you mentioned, when one of my questions went to the "inconstructive" categorization some days ago. I understand why, but didn't realize at the very beginning. What I not yet understand is, what sort of impact this category has on my question right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close reason now points to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), which in turn points to the good subjective guidelines from the [What kind of questions should I not ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) section.