# Closing questions with specific reasons

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we have specified reasons to close questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95960/why-do-we-have-specified-reasons-to-close-questions)

I am not a regular here at meta, but it seems to me that "Why was my question closed?"-questions are pretty common. Would it not be a good idea to solve these meta questions in the appropriate forum, instead of here at meta?

I mean, is it the function of meta to be some kind of appeal or explanation forum? Surely the people who close the question are better suited to explain why it was closed? It seems to me that giving a specific explanation for closing a question is a good idea.

Would it be too hard to remove the default close reasons, e.g. *"It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."*, and replace them with a user specified reason, e.g. "You need to be more specific about your question."

As voting to close a question is a reputation privilege, perhaps it can be divided in two categories:

1. Creating a reason to close a
   question
2. Supporting existing reasons to close
   a question.

Yes, I agree, sometimes the questions are so bad you just think they merit an investment in time and effort, but on the other hand, a reason does not need to be more specific than: "Go read the FAQ about asking questions." or "You keep asking bad questions, and do not follow the advice you are given." etc.

If you leave generic reasons as an option, in my experience people will use them, rather than go to the trouble of formulating a proper response, even when such a response is rather easy to write.

Comment: There's always chat.

Comment: @Yi Jiang I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: @TLP: I think Yi is saying that if you are unsure of why a question was closed, maybe try asking someone in one of the chat-rooms.

Comment: @Adam Bernier Isn't chat rooms reputation restricted? I am not asking for my own sake, I've never had a question closed. I've only ever posted two questions (on SO, that is), and only because I thought I should ask *something*. :)

Comment: I got the feeling you weren't asking about your own questions. And, yes, chat requires 20 rep.

Comment: this is what comments are for. So if you feel that way, simply *leave a comment on the post explaining in more detail.*

Comment: @Jeff The problem to solve was how to reduce the number of people who come to meta to ask why their question was closed.

Comment: there is no such problem to be solved -- we don't have huge numbers (or even large to moderate numbers) of people doing what you are describing; the existing close reasons, plus the faq links, seem to suffice for most people wondering why their questions were closed.

Comment: @Jeff I see. Perhaps I got the wrong impression, then.

Answer (score 4):

I have voted to close your question because olly-wolly polly woggy ump bump fizz.

Comment: How is that a valid reason to close?

Comment: @Josh: Exactly. This is the problem I have with a "fill in the blank" close reason.  People will just close as "I don't like the question," which is not a valid reason to close.

Comment: @TLP: Exactly.  The only way to force people to use valid close reasons is to require them to pick one from a list.

Comment: @Robert No, that would be "the only way to force people to **pretend** to use a valid reason". I am surprised only I see this distinction. If you want people to be vague, allow them to use blanket statements, such as "Well, your question was either too long, or too short, too specific or too broad."

Comment: @TLP: Robert has explained the point I was making. There have been some other discussions in this vein, mostly around requiring comments for downvotes.

Comment: @TLP: There have been at least a few times when I have seen a question on SO, rolled my eyes, groaned, tried to find a reason to close vote it, and had my hand stayed by the fact that I just couldn't justify it using the list of official reasons. It _does_ affect close vote behavior.

Comment: @Josh I was making the assumption that any given reason to close a question would have to be reasonable, and follow some sort of guidelines. But perhaps that is too complicated.

Comment: @TLP: That would be the ideal, of course, and close votes are subject to a lot more scrutiny than downvotes (and they're able to be counteracted, and not anonymous), but I think this is a fatal loophole. It would even be possible for a person to give a reason that sounds plausible, but isn't really valid; then everyone ends up arguing both about the question _and_ the reason.

Comment: @Josh I guess that what I am mostly objecting to is the very generic close reasons that I see. They do not give the OP's a lot of information, which leads them to come to meta and ask questions.

Comment: @TLP: That's understandable. Leaving a comment about the close vote can be helpful, but there's really no way to require it. Also, as far as I know, Meta is indeed the "court of appeals" for closed questions, so there's no need to worry on that score. Some questions do in fact get reopened when appealed here; some don't.

Comment: @TLP: we can and do strive to improve the usefulness of the close reason descriptions. If you have suggestions for improvement, please post them.