# Due Dilligence in Marking Questions as Off-Topic

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, moderation

As a BlackBerry developer I consider this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024157/message-related-event-handling-in-blackberry-10?noredirect=1#comment28122275_19024157

to be entirely valid. The situation the question poser is in is due to the development trajectory of the BlackBerry API, in this case support for Headless Applications, rather than problems with code he may have written. Not all BlackBerry developers will necessarily be aware of the all subtle factors as the OS development progresses, but some are. Stackoverflow should be a natural venu to ask those questions, but it is difficult to make any progress when the questions are put on hold because members with enough authority to do so, don't understand the question in context of the OS.

The end result is a reduction of the utility of Stackoverflow by unecessarily delaying an answer to the question.

Comment: Please read the reason the question is off topic in the close reason - do you disagree with it? Also, please register the distinction between a valid question and one which is answerable in reasonable length.

Comment: So is this meta post just a discussion about that one specific question, in which you're requesting it be reopened, or are you trying to discuss closing/moderation habits in general.  Currently it seems to be half and half.  I'd suggest picking one of the two.

Comment: I have already marked the question for re-opening. I have an answer for it alread, so yes I disagree with the reason for closing and it is answerable in a reasonable length.

Comment: The issue of closing questions for the wrong reason is a problem with potentially more impact on the utility of stack overflow than having questions that fall outside the bounds, and I think it needs to be address. Using a recent occurance as an example illustrates the problem more clearly.

Comment: It's reopened.  However, without a decent edit I could see it being closed again.  Perhaps you could help, seeing how you pled his case?

Comment: @Richard If this is a general discussion and not just a single reopen request you should be more specific about what your problem is.  Start with a thesis of what problem you think there is.  Is there a pattern of lots of questions being incorrectly closed?  Is it an issue with diamonds closing instead of letting 5 users vote to close?  Or what?  Then, after a succinct summary, explain in more detail what the problem is, the effects of that problem, etc.  More than one example would also be best.  Then, optionally, but ideally, include some proposed solutions to the problem.

Comment: The **normal** procedure is to edit the question into shape *first*, then nominate it for reopening. Without editing this question is just heading for the close queue again.

Comment: My point is there is nothing wrong with the question as it stands if you understand it.

Comment: @Won't done. [15]

Comment: Richard, you never answered the comment from @Emrakul above if and how you disagree with the specific 'off-topic' close reason. How does that question "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"?

Comment: Now _this_ is why "does not demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem" should not be under "off-topic".  To people that have been around a while it's perfectly clear, but to people coming off other sites they'd believe that off-topic would refer to the question's topic being outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Richard isn't exactly a new user though.  He has 7k rep and has been here for 5 years.

Answer (score 3):

> *it is difficult to make any progress when the questions are put on hold because members with enough authority to do so, don't understand the question in context of the OS*

Users with enough reputation to vote to close (and moderators) have been answering, asking, editing, reading, reviewing, voting up/down/close and making useful comments enough time to know that

> [image: down vote tooltip]

There's no mystery, they are easily recognizable, heavily downvoted and quickly closed: ***[Gimme teh codez](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135049/185667)*** questions don't have language or OS barriers, they spread from tag `<a>` to `<z>`. The aim of this network is on quality Q&A's and a durable repository of community curated knowledge.

With that in mind, there's nothing stopping you [from asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a good, on-topic, well-researched Question. Leave that one alone and put much more spice and technical knowledge into yours.